# Airplane mode not responding, activated by default

Tags: wireless, 15.10, intel-wireless, airplane-mode

System info:
Asus K501UB, i7 6500, 8GB ram
Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Problem:

1. By default, the airplane mode is on.
2. The keyboard <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does not work at changing it.
3. If I try `sudo rfkill list` I get

   ```
   1: asus-wlan: wireless LAN
   Soft Blocked: yes
   Hard Blocked: no
   2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft Blocked: yes
   Hard Blocked: no
   3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft Blocked: yes
   Hard Blocked: no
   ```
4. If I try `sudo rfkill unblock all` I get

   ```
   1: asus-wlan: wireless LAN
   Soft Blocked: no
   Hard Blocked: no
   2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft Blocked: no
   Hard Blocked: no
   3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft Blocked: no
   Hard Blocked: yes
   ```
5. There is no physical switch to turn on and off wifi or airplane mode (that I know of). It works perfectly in windows 10.
6. If I try to access by the GUI, the state of the airplane LED is inverted to what the Airplane Mode switch says. (switch says Airplane mode OFF, LED is ON and vice versa)
7. `iwconfig` returns everything related to wlp3s0 in an OFF state and no reference to phy0. What the hell is wlp3s0 ?
8. `lspci -nn` returns amongst other things

   ```
    03:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev59)
   ```

Comment: I had this problem when waking up from suspend! When suspended again and returned, somehow WiFi would start showing connections, try it...

Comment: Ok I tried it, and turns out I have found a new problem to my new setup ... When I suspend and return it is LAGGY as hell, I cannot type and click anywhere. However, if the Airplane LED is on before, after suspend, it is off. I cannot validate with the other elements because nothing seems to be working. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Ok, So I looked up to update the driver for Intel 7265 using Kernel 4.2+ from intel website. It turns out that the firmware are not loaded by udev (or something like that). I did the verification according to this link: [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware#How_is_Firmware_Used.3F). So I am lost now. I do not know what to do honestly.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`? and did you have to tweak your BIOS when installing 15.10?

Comment: Turns out the laggy wake up from suspend was due to the Nouveau driver for Nvidia 940m. I switched to proprietary driver and it is now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

and reboot.

This should unblock wireless. But there may be other issues with Intel 7265 adapter.

Comment: I typed that in and it worked straight away. Thank you very much for your help