# Wireless hardware switch turned off, probably because Airplane Mode stuck turned on

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

I bought a used MSI U230 laptop with Windows installed. I immediately installed Ubuntu 14.04 in its place, so I don't know if wireless was working on Windows. But in Ubuntu, it's telling me "wi-fi is disabled via hardware switch".

Running `rfkill list all` returns:

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

My laptop has no hardware switch. As per [this page](http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/wireless-how-to-turn-on-off-wireless-on-laptops.html), I tried pressing `fn-f11`, which didn't do anything.

I also read that unplugging the laptop, taking out the battery, and pressing the power button for 30 seconds would turn the hardware switch on, but again, that did nothing.

Then I tried booting to BIOS, selecting `Default Settings => yes` and `Save & Exit => yes`, but once again, nothing. The command `rfkill unblock all` doesn't do anything either.

So I opened Settings and went to Network. Turns out, Airplane Mode is turned on as well. There's a switch for Airplane Mode and a switch for Wireless. If I turn on the switch for Wireless, it just switches automatically back to off. If I turn off the switch for Airplane Mode, it stays off, but then when I exit out of Settings and enter it again, it's once again switched on.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: According to the manual: https://www.msi.com/Notebook/support/U230.html#down-manual it is Fn+F8.

Comment: @chili555 Wow, can't believe it was that simple, but yeah that solve it. Thanks!! If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Posted. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consult the manual that can be downloaded here: https://www.msi.com/Notebook/support/U230.html#down-manual The key combination for wireless is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. I hope it will enable your wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699398/airplane-mode-not-responding-activated-by-default):

Run this in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

It is work for me

Comment: Why would you use tee in this instance?

Comment: @ElderGeek Using `sudo tee` like this provides [a handy way of writing text to a file as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/230517/22949).